# Exception: ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, database-connection

I am doing a simple JSP program to connect with MySQL DB. But it's showing the Exception like this. I am using Java version 1.6 and MySQL -connector 5.1.20. I have placed this connector (.jar) file in lib/ext directory of JAVA_HOME. I have set the CLASSPATH also to the value upto connector (.JAR) file. Still, I get the same Exception.

I have searched for this. I did all the things suggested by them. But I didn't found any results.

Please help me.

Comment: Are you using eclipse to execute this ?

Comment: I mean are you using any IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans for the project.If not use it.It will be easier to debug when there are any issues.

Comment: I am runnin in localhost like localhost:8080/jsp/Connect.jsp. I am not using any IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the connector jar in the TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder of your tomcat installation. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Netbeans, then right click on your project, select "Add library," then select MySQL JDBC driver and save it.

Comment: I am not using any IDE, I am using Tomcat to run it